# Enforcing referential integrity from one table to any table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a variety of tables that represent business objects, e.g. Products, People, Locations and I'm wanting to add a Tags table (as in taxonomy).

```
CREATE TABLE Tags (
    tagId bigint IDENTITY,
    name nvarchar(50)
)
```

How can I allow multiple tags to be applied to multiple types of entities in a way that allows the DBMS to enforce referential integrity without needing a linking table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TagUse (
    tagId bigint,
    productId bigint NULL,
    personId bigint NULL,
    locationId bigint NULL,
    ...        
    whateverId bigint NULL
)
```

Or worse:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonTags (
    tagId bigint,
    personId bigint
)

CREATE TABLE LocationTags (
    tagId bigint,
    locationId bigint
)

...

CREATE TABLE WhateverTags (
    tagId bigint,
    whateverId bigint
)
```

I just thought of a third option: rather than having separate `*Tags` tables for each entity, each entity can be thought of inheriting from "`Taggable`" which is then referenced-to by the child tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Taggable (
    taggableId bigint,
    tagId bigint
)

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    personId bigint,
    ...
    taggableId bigint
)
```

Comment: Both those psossibilities are preferred over what you want to do. Because there is no way to have referential integrity with the design you want. It quite frankly is a SQL Antipattern.  Frankly I prefer the second one.

Comment: @HLGEM I thought of a third option.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a **sequence object**:

```
CREATE TABLE [TaggableObjects] (
    objectId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

CREATE TABLE [Persons] (
    objectId BIGINT, -- referencing Objects.objectId
    name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE [Locations] (
    objectId BIGINT, -- referencing Objects.objectId
    country VARCHAR(50)
)
```

In programming languages like `Java` and `C#` you'd call `Persons` and `Locations` an extension of `TaggableObject`.

Following this you could implement the `Tags` as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Tags] (
    tagId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    objectId BIGINT
)
```

Though the problem with an implementation like this one would be that you have to figure out the best way to identify of what type `Tags.objectId` is.

Note that depending on which engine you'll be using, many support some sort of functionality to more easily implement a sequence object, you might want to right up on it.